# Incompatible Types

Tags: java

This is my main method

```
import java.util.*;
public class Cities 
{
    static String [] extractCity (String [] cityStateZip)
    {
       int location;
       ArrayList<String> cities= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityStateZip));

       for (int i=0; i < cities.size(); i++)
        {
          cities.get(i);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<cityStateZip.length; i++)
        {
           if (cityStateZip[i] == null || cityStateZip[i].equals(" "))
               break;
           cities.add(cityStateZip[i].substring(0, cityStateZip[i].indexOf(",")));
       }

       return cities;
    } 
}
```

The error is in 'return cities', showing that it is of incompatible types. I know it's expecting an int, but I'm not sure how to fix it. (I've already viewed similar questions, but I do not seem to quite grasp the concept)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it's expecting an `int`? What type is `cities`? What type is your method's return type?

Comment: Can you add in the stacktrace?

Comment: @Ascalonian There's no stack trace.  It's a compile error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to just show the error message they were getting

Comment: It looks like the method is expecting a String[], not an int.

Comment: `static ArrayList<String> extractCity(...)`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Cities is a String and my method is also returning a string but when I go on to compile it, it shows me that it is expecting an int instead of a String.

Comment: @Andrea `cities` is not a `String`. If it were a `String`, it would be declared as `String cities`. Instead, you have `ArrayList<String> cities`. `ArrayList<String>` is not the same as `String[]` and the compiler is telling you that in the compiler error. And Sotirios Delimanolis is kind enough to ask you about this in order for you to learn rather than providing an easy-rep answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I see my error, thank you. I'm relatively new to learning how ArrayList works, so your feedback really does help a lot.

Answer (score 8):

`cities` isn't an `String[]` it is a `List<String>`. Return a `String[]` like

```
return cities.toArray(new String[0]);
```

or modify the return type of the method like

```
static List<String> extractCity (String [] cityStateZip)
```

Answer (score 6):

extractCity should return an array of strings, but you try returning an ArrayList of String instead.

Do it like this:

```
return cities.toArray(new String[cities.size()]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function is declared to return a "string array", not an int. "cities" is an ArrayList of Strings.

An `ArrayList<String>` is not an array of strings. (this is where your error comes from)

One possible solution: Change your method to return ArrayList

eg:

```
public static ArrayList<String> extractCity(String[] cityStateZip) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static String [] extractCity (String [] cityStateZip){
  ArrayList<String> cities= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cityStateZip));
  return cities.toArray(new String[cities.size()]);
}
```

Change return type to `String []`